# Kendo Grid showing all records even when page size is defined

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, grid

I'm new to kendo UI, I am trying to implement Kendo grid with Webapi, paging does not take any effect below is the code.
The API

```
  public IList<Customer> GetCustomers(int take, int skip)
        {
            this.Customers = FillData.Customers;
            this.Orders = FillData.Orders;
            return Customers.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
        }
```

And the javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "json",
                    transport: {
                        read: "/api/GridData/GetCustomers",
                        dataType: "json" 
                    },
                    pageSize: 6,
                    serverPaging: true,
                },
                height: 600,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                //detailInit: detailInit,
                //dataBound: function () {
                //    this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
                //},
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: "FirstName",
                        title: "First Name",
                        width: "110px"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "LastName",
                        title: "Last Name",
                        width: "110px"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "Country",
                        width: "110px"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "City",
                        width: "110px"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "Title"
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
```

The same thing with the Odata service telerik has provided works well.

Comment: If you look at the API calls being sent from the client, does it have the parameters in for skip and take in the query ?

Comment: Probably not related, but `type: "json"` is incorrect and unnecessary in your data source configuration.

Comment: Additionally, you don't define a `schema` in your data source and you don't return the total number of customers in your server response. The grid will have no idea how many pages of data there are if it doesn't know how many total items there are in the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I wrote a blog post couple of months back - [Kendo UI Grid - Server Side Paging, Filtering and Sorting](http://musabmjafri.blogspot.com/2015/02/kendo-ui-grid-server-side-paging.html). This should resolve your query. Major focus in the post is on sending the right parameters to the WebAPI. I have shown a sample grid and datasource code as well request and response objects sent to the WebAPI. Let me know if you need any explanations.

Edit: Posting it all here since link only is not appreciated.

**The Grid**

Below is a Kendo UI Grid declaration for which we will implement the server side manipulation.

```
$("#sampleGrid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        { field: "ID", title: "ID", width: 50 },
        { field: "Label", title: "Label", template: "<span class='k-link bold' title='${Description}'>${Label}</span>" },
        { field: "Description", title: "Description" }
    ],
    dataBound: function () { this.element.find('tbody tr:first').addClass('k-state-selected') },
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: [10, 15, 20, 25]
    },
    resizable: true,
    reorderable: true,
    filterable: true,
    groupable: true,
    selectable: true,
    sortable: true
});
```

**The DataSource**

The below DataSource sends a call to a server method, address to which is saved in svcSampleUrl and assigned to it in the "transport" property. There is no need to make an ajax call separately to fetch the data for the datasource,

Setting serverPaging, serverFiltering, and serverSorting as true enables the Kendo UI Grid DataSource to send server calls when any one of the following events are triggered by the user; change of page, change in filters, and change in sorting of a column.

```
var sampleDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: svcSampleUrl,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json"
        },
        parameterMap: function (options) {
            model.Take = options.take;
            model.Skip = options.skip;
            model.Sort = options.sort;
            model.Filter = options.filter;
            return kendo.stringify(model);
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: "sampleDTOList",
        //  another way to accept the response if some particular values need processing
        //data: function (response) {
        //  //some implementation with the response values
        //  return response.WorklistDTOList;
        //},
        total: "totalItems",
        model: {
            fields: {
                ID: { type: "number" },
                Label: { type: "string" },
                Description: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    },
    serverPaging: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    pageSize: 10,
});
```

The parameter map property allows us to send a set of default parameters along with our custom ones back to the server. The default parameters include "take", "skip", "sort", and "filter" that correspond to page size, amount of records to skip, sort criteria, and filter criteria array respectively. Since one may require to send other parameters as well, the default parameter values are set in the model that has other values. Kendo.stringify is applied to the model and returned as a complete request object.

**Data and Total**

The DataSource schema contains two properties; "data" and "total". Each of these are the names of attributes in the response object in which we expect our results. I have assigned "sampleDTOList" to the "data" property since my response object will contain the list of records under that name. Similarly, I have assigned "totalItems" to "total" property. The "total" property accepts a numerical value of the count of all records irrespective of how many are returned on the current page. That way the DataSource knows how many records there are in actual and how many pages to show.

Note: The model is not explored here and is just referenced as a place holder for any model that can be used.

**The Request**

The Request object contains the exact attributes as the default and custom parameters the DataSource is set to send to the server.

```
public class FilterDTO
{
    public int Take { get; set; }
    public int Skip { get; set; }
    public List<SortCriteria> Sort { get; set; }
    public List<FilterCriteria> Filter { get; set; }

    public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class SortCriteria
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string dir { get; set; }
}

public class FilterCriteria
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string operator { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

**The Server End**

This is where we receive the call with all the parameters needed to manipulate the data. This is a simple method that can call a database stored procedure with all the parameters for the filtered results. The stored procedure should then return a dataset according to the given page size, amount of records to skip, sort criteria, filter criteria array and any other filter parameter that me have been sent by the model included in the call request. Page number though requires to be calculated from the information we have.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("GetItems")]
public SampleResponse GetItems(FilterDTO filterDTO)
{
    //Calling a different layer for the read operation based in the parameter values
    return BusinessLayer.GetItems(filterDTO);
}
```

**Page Number**

Since we receive "take" and "skip" from client end of the application, calculating required paged number is easy from the information given. When we know page size and amount of records to skip, we can obtain the page number by applying the following rule:

```
pageNo = (skip + take) / take
```

**The Response**

The Response object contains the two attributes needed by the DataSource as mentioned before; one for the "data" and one for the "total" property of the schema.

```
public class SampleResponse : BaseResponse
{
    private List<SampleItems> SampleDTOList;
    public List<SampleItems> sampleDTOList
    {
        get { return SampleDTOList; }
        set { SampleDTOList = value; }
    }
    public int totalItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers.

Comment: There was no need for a vote down here, the link was my own content and not something found randomly on the internet.. a simple request to place the answer material here instead of just posting the link would have been sufficient

Comment: Now you have a real nice answer. Btw it wasn't me who downvoted you. Instead, I will upvote this.

Comment: Hi Musub, what's model in the parameterMap                     parameterMap: function (options) {
            model.Take = options.take;
            model.Skip = options.skip;
            model.Sort = options.sort;
            model.Filter = options.filter;
            return kendo.stringify(model);
        }

Comment: Plus what if I want a type get method

Comment: model is an object on js level. this object is not mandatory of course, you can just stringify options directly. But in my previous project I had some extra params and filters for which I required a custom object.

Comment: get method for what exactly... didn't understand the requirement... you wish to get the results separately and bind them to the grid?